# Can I use the physical socket id of a CPU to determine which cluster it belongs on an ARM big.LITTLE SoC?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

I'm currently trying to determine the quantities of cpus in each cpu cluster of a big.LITTLE architecture from userspace.

I'm looking at files on sysfs to see if any of them can give the information I need. I noticed that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/uevent` can give me the processor type for that cpu id, so I could get the cluster size by parsing it. 
 The file is given like this:

> OF_NAME=cpu 
>   OF_FULLNAME=/cpus/cpu@100 
>   OF_TYPE=cpu 
>   OF_COMPATIBLE_0=arm,cortex-a53 
>   OF_COMPATIBLE_1=arm,armv8 
>   OF_COMPATIBLE_N=2 
>   MODALIAS=cpu:type:aarch64:feature:,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007

Where I could parse the name *cortex-a53* and then define the cluster by it, since the other cluster would have *cortex-a73* instead. But that seems like a lot of work just to find out the cluster size.

When looking at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/topology`, I noticed that the `physical_package_id` maps exactly to the distribution of cores in my architecture: 6 little cores and 2 big cores.

After searching a bit, I found that the physical_package_id represents the physical socket to which the cpu belongs.

**Can I determine to which cluster of a big.LITTLE architecture a core belongs by looking at its physical socket?**

EDIT: I ran this script to find out the CPU topology:

```bsh
CPU_NUMBER=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | wc -l)
LAST_INDEX="$(($CPU_NUMBER-1))"

for i in $(seq 0 $LAST_INDEX)
do
    echo "Core $i: "
    cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/topology/physical_package_id
done
```

Answer (score 0):

After hopping around in the linux source code. I believe that my assumptions are correct and it seems, for what I could understand, that they use the physical_package_id to identify the cluster in the [driver for big.LITTLE architectures](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/cpufreq/arm_big_little.c#L78) in the two following methods.

```c
static inline int raw_cpu_to_cluster(int cpu)
{
    return topology_physical_package_id(cpu);
}
static inline int cpu_to_cluster(int cpu)
{
    return is_bL_switching_enabled() ?
        MAX_CLUSTERS : raw_cpu_to_cluster(cpu);
}
```

And then use it to get the frequency table in another method, which is part of what I want to do as well:

```c
static int bL_cpufreq_init(struct cpufreq_policy *policy)
{
    u32 cur_cluster = cpu_to_cluster(policy->cpu);

   /* Some code here */

   policy->freq_table = freq_table[cur_cluster];

   /* Some more code here */
}
```

So I believe I can count the number of CPU cores in each cluster by looking at the physical_package_id for each one of them.